# how to use angular material popup without using $event

Tags: angularjs

It can be very easy to do, but I am not able to open angular material dialog without using `$event`. Actually I have multiple dropdown and I want to open `AngularJS material dialog` on change of options for this I am using `ng-change` but I heard that `$event` does not support in `ng-change`, so my popup is not getting open. Can you please help me out in this?

```
<select id="{{ques.qustnnreQustnId}}" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedValueYesNo" ng-change="ctrl.fillAnswerAndQuestionQuestionnaireid(ques.qustnnreQustnId,selectedValueYesNo,ques.saveRequired,$event);" required>
      <!--ng-change="ctrl.open(ques.qustnnreQustnId,selectedValueYesNo,ques.saveRequired,event);" required-->
      <option value=""></option>
      <option ng-repeat="q in ques.answerList" value="{{q.answerDisplayText}}"
         ng-selected="{{q.answered == true}}">
         {{q.answerDisplayText}}
      </option>
   </select>

public open(event: any) {
            let options: angular.material.IDialogOptions = {
                controller: QuestionnaireController,
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/Dialogbox.html',
                targetEvent: event,
                clickOutsideToClose: false,
                fullscreen: false,
                locals: {
                    message: "Evaluated result will be discarded if you continue. Are you sure you want to continue?"
                },
                bindToController: true,
                onRemoving: function (a, b, c) {
                    let x = '';
                }
            };
            this.$mdDialog.show(options);
        }
```

Comment: Please create plnkr or fiddle for same.